# Django. Rest framework hyphen in xml tag

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Need advice. I have a tag, `property-type`, it uses a hyphen. I know that in python you cannot use hyphens for variables. As a result, I have:

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from listings.models import *

class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property_type = serializers.CharField(source='xml_data_property_type')

    class Meta:
        model = KV
        fields = ['title', 'price', 'address', 'property_type']
```

In order for `xml` to work correctly, I need that the tag, `property-type`, be written with a **hyphen**.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by by overriding the `__init__()` method of the serializer:

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = KV
        fields = ['title', 'price', 'address']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # On serializer initialize,
        # create a new field
        # property-type

        # Note:
        # Here you can use hyphens,
        # since the field name is declared as string.

        self.fields.update({
            'property-type': serializers.CharField(source='xml_data_property_type')
        })
```

Comment: wencakisa, hello Thanks for the answer - it works! Super!

Comment: @I.Z. I'm glad that I helped you. :)